# Restructuring Meteor App

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am restructuring my meteor application when suddenly every view (html template) that has its logic (the JS script) separated from the initial file stop working.

initially my project looked like this

```
-project
   -.meteor
   -client
      -templateA.html
      -templateB.html
      -templateC.html
      -client.js <-- contain JS for all template
      -display.css 
   -server
      -server.js
   -model.js <--collections
   -router.js <-- iron-router router
```

But as the project grows, it became hard for me to manage whole js code in a single file. So I decided to separate it into smaller modules. so it became like this

```
 -project
    -.meteor
    -client
       -views
          -templateA.html
          -tempplateA.js 
          -templateB.html
          -templateB.js
          -templateC.html
          -client.js <---templateC JS is still in client.js
       -stylesheets
          -display.css

    -server
       -server.js
    -model.js
    -router.js
```

Every view (template) does not work. The browser only generate blank page. However, I managed to generate templateC. So my deduction is, templateC works since the JS is still in the original file.

What should I do to make it work to the rest of the templates?

Comment: Why did you put your server directory inside your client directory? Is there any error appearing in your browser console?

Comment: @JulienLeCoupanec sorry indentation typos, the server is outside of client.

Comment: What you did to separate the javascript code for each template seems to be good to me. It should work. Is there any error appearing in your browser console?

Comment: @JulienLeCoupanec no error :(. I am at my wit's end. Where else can I check the error?

Comment: Meteor concatenates all files, so what code is in which file makes no difference. The error must be somewhere else. Either you've lost a few chars or lines while moving, or left a duplicate, or you're trying to use local variables outside of the files they're defined. Each of those should yield some error though.

Comment: @HubertOG from what I know from my limited experience, I can only debug/see the errors from web consoles. Is there any other way?

Comment: You mean a browser console? That should be enough.

Comment: @HubertOG Ok now I checked with the Chrome console, it says a function is not defined. I have moved the function to `project/lib` so that it will be loaded first but still the problem occurs. What should I do?

Comment: @HubertOG I solved it by putting it into client/compatibility folder. Why is it not working if i put it in client/lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/client/compatibility` was a key to your problem.

Variables you define in a JS file are local to that file. [See this section.](http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing)

---

Basically, Meteor wraps each separate file with `(function(){ ... })();` pattern. This means that when you define:

```
var something = {};
```

in one file, then `something` is `undefined` in another. If you want to create a variable that will be shared in the whole app, you need to make it a global variable. Fortunately, that's simple – just remove the `var` keyword:

```
something = {};
```

Now you can use `something` anywhere in your code.